# Does App Store Connect track widget installs on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios14, widgetkit

I only see installs for my main app in the "App Analytics" section, but nothing regarding extensions like widgets. Where can I find that information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not. You can use the [`WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter/getcurrentconfigurations(_:)) when your app is launched to get information about which widgets the user have added to their home screen.

You can then send this information to your analytics source of choice.